# Is there a way to pan in sublime text 2?

Tags: workflow, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2

Does anyone know of a sublime text plugin that allows you to pan code similar to a Photoshop file canvas?

Space+drag or Middle Mouse+drag?

I can imagine this becoming useful if you don't have text wrapping on in a very tall document. If a plugin doesn't exist then it might be possible that I could start work on one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way yet, I added feature request on the website, you can upvote.

http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/159170-drag-scroll-or-pan-or-touch-scroll/

I looked into plugin API, and it seems not to provide a way to implement this as a plugin.